# Response to parse contains hashtag / # in the url. Parameters are not parsed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, ruby-on-rails-5

A server I need responses with a url with a # (hashtag) in the url. Rails ignores the following parameters.

http://localhost:3000/#parameter1=one&parameter2=two...

So rails only sees the part before the # http://localhost:3000

Is there anyway I can replace the # with a ? before the url is parsed by Rails ?

Answer (score 1):

I added the following javascript code within my app/assets/application.js to rewrite the url on the whole site.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  if (window.location.href.indexOf('#') > 0) {
    window.location = window.location.href.replace(/#/, '?');
  }
});
```